# Get an array of values into a cell within a dataframe

Tags: python, r, json, data-manipulation

**Update : I re-worded and re-thought through this, and I think the question is better asked like this.**

So I've been hacking at this forever with no luck. Here is an example of what I am looking to do.

I am starting off with a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame("one" = c(1,11), "two" = c(2,22), "three" = c(3,33))

one  two  three
1    2    3
11   22   33
```

I am attempting to turn the above, into this:

```
one  new
1    c(2,3)
11    c(22,33)
```

I have tried a few things like nesting the 2 columns and trying to map over them, etc. Maybe there is something simple I am not seeing here. I'd preferably like to do this in R via the tidyverse, but at this point I'm open to whatever.

It has to be this way because when it gets converted to JSON the values under 'new' need to be in the form [1,2,3] & [11,22,33]. Maybe its easier in Python?

I'm using the *jsonlite* package in R for converting to/from JSON.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for the responses.. I edited the question.. hopefully its clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should just be a `Map` exercise:

```
df$new <- Map(c, df$two, df$three)
df
#  one two three    new
#1   1   2     3   2, 3
#2  11  22    33 22, 33

library(jsonlite)
toJSON(df[c("one","new")])
#[{"one":1,"new":[2,3]},{"one":11,"new":[22,33]}]
```

If you've got many variables, you can wrap it in `do.call` to get it done too:

```
df$new <- do.call(Map, c(c,df[2:3]))
```

If *tidyverse* is your preference, you can *purrr* it like:

```
map2(df$two, df$three, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[11,22,33]], columns=["one", "two","three"])
   one  two  three
0    1    2      3
1   11   22     33

df['new'] = list(zip(df.two, df.three))

df[['one','new']].to_json(orient='records')
# '[{"one":1,"new":[2,3]},{"one":11,"new":[22,33]}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use `tidyr::nest()`, after you `group_by()`:

```
library(dplyr)

nest_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(one) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(c(two, three), .key="new")
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# one new             
#   <dbl> <list>          
# 1     1 <tibble [1 x 2]>
# 2    11 <tibble [1 x 2]>
```

Now the column `new`, in each row is a `tibble()`.

```
nest_df[1, ][[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#     two three
#    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     3
```

`toJSON()`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(one) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(c(two, three), .key="new") %>% 
  jsonlite::toJSON()
#[{"one":1,"new":[{"two":2,"three":3}]},{"one":11,"new":[{"two":22,"three":33}]}]
```